# How to assign Model search() data to CHtml::listData in Yii 1?

Tags: drop-down-menu, yii

How to assign Model search() data to CHtml::listData in Yii 1?

My Code:

```
//Get Company for dropdown
 $model       = new Company();
 $companies   = $model->search();
 $companyList = CHtml::listData($companies,'id','company_name');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shoudn't do it that way. By default search() method return CActiveDataProvider, which uses with CGridView and so on. If you need to use it with `CHtml::listData()` do it that way:

```
// Here you can set criteria to findAll if you need
$companies = Company::model()->findAll();
$companyList = CHtml::listData($companies,'id','company_name');
```

Comment: But will the method findAll() include all conditions/criteria that I have already set in method search()?

Comment: You may create another method searchCriteria() which returns CDbCriteria and use it with findAll: `Company::model()->findAll(Company::searchCriteria());`. But usualy such conditions defined with `scopes` to use this way: `Company::model()->active()->hasLogo()->findAll()`